# Curl request to python request

Tags: python, curl, python-requests

I have a curl request as below:

```
curl -X POST \
https://example.com \
-H 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data' \
--form-string 'message=<messageML>Hello world!</messageML>'
```

How do i pass --form-string data in python request?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`files`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file) parameter to post your data, example:

```
import requests

url = 'https://httpbin.org/anything'
data = {'message':'<messageML>Hello world!</messageML>'}
r = requests.post(url, files=data)

print(r.text)
```

You don't have to use `headers` because 'multipart/form-data' is the default 'Content-Type' header when posting files.