# Translating Bash cURL commands to Python

Tags: python, python-requests, pycurl

I have the below working in Bash. How would this be written in Python using requests or pycurl?

```
curl -o .output_data.xml -v --cert ../cert/my_cert.pem:password123 -k 'https://my.target.url' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"document":{"header":{"exportType":"XML"}}}'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Curl request to python request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47027655/curl-request-to-python-request)

Comment: Thanks but I tried something like this answer and it did not work, the challenge here, for me at least, is passing the cert and password combination, which I can not get to work using requests

Comment: I tried to read the `curl` manual page to figure out what exactly this does, but it's rather impenetrable. Is the password something which gets passed to the server, or is it used to decrypt the PEM file locally? Can you find a public site where this can be tested?

Comment: `requests` accepts a `cert` param which seems to map 1:1 to the above example. Have you been able to try it out yet? `requests.get(url, cert='/path/to/pem/file')`

Comment: the cert sits client side, which you generate server side with a user defined password.  Yes I tried requests.get(url, cert='/path/to/pem/file') which returns an authentication error. I dont think it is posssible with requests https://github.com/psf/requests/issues/1573, which is why I added pycurl to the title

Comment: https://github.com/psf/requests/issues/1573#issuecomment-169916326 shows how to do this with pyCurl. There are also comments suggesting workarounds for `requests` but I can't assess them. Again, it would be helpful to find a public web site where this could be tested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the comment from Tripleee regarding
https://github.com/psf/requests/issues/1573#issuecomment-169916326 the below snippet now works:

I just needed to map the cURL option arguments correctly:

```
--cert maps to c.setopt(pycurl.SSLCERT, cert_file_path) and c.setopt(pycurl.SSLKEYPASSWD, "password123")

-k maps to c.setopt(pycurl.SSL_VERIFYPEER, False)

-H maps to c.setopt(pycurl.HTTPHEADER,["Content-Type: application/json"])

-d maps to c.setopt(pycurl.POSTFIELDS, json.dumps(params))
```

there is no mapping for `-o` so I capture the output using a buffer `c.setopt(b.WRITEFUNCTION, b.write)`.

`b.getvalue()` will allow me to later parse the data from the captured XML string using Element Tree or similar.

```
import pycurl
import io
import json

cert_file_path = "../cert/my_cert.pem"
url = "https://my.target.url"
params={"document":{"header":{"exportType":"XML"}}}

b = io.BytesIO()
c = pycurl.Curl()
c.setopt(pycurl.URL, url)
c.setopt(pycurl.SSLCERT, cert_file_path)
c.setopt(pycurl.SSLKEYPASSWD, "password123")
c.setopt(pycurl.SSL_VERIFYPEER, False)
c.setopt(pycurl.HTTPHEADER,["Content-Type: application/json"])
c.setopt(pycurl.POSTFIELDS, json.dumps(params)) 
c.setopt(c.WRITEFUNCTION, b.write)
c.perform()
xml_string = b.getvalue().decode('UTF-8')
```

Comment: Thank you for updating with the correct method. Please consider adding in a summary of what was wrong and what you fixed

Comment: Thanks - I have edited the answer with some explanations

Answer (score -5):

you can use :

```
bashCommand = "curl -o .output_data.xml -L -X GET -v --cert ../cert/my_cert.pem:password123 -k 'https://my.target.url' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"document":{"header":{"exportType":"XML"}}}'"
import subprocess
process = subprocess.Popen(bashCommand.split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output, error = process.communicate()
```

Comment: The OP asked for a solution on how to make curl requests using python requests package or pycurl. Your example uses subprocess nad just passes the curl command.

Comment: this is not a good solution and could be highly inefficient (also reliant on the `curl` tool being installed). I feel `requests` library would be more high level and better overall.